# Profitability of a treasury security

Tags: systems-of-equations, finance

Calculate the profitability rate of the following investment:
Treasury security with nominal value of $1 000 000$ and $8\%$ coupon, 90 days to maturity and price of $1005000$ however you buy it 60 days before maturity.

I am stuck with idea of profitability of treasury security with coupons. Because i thought it could be: $(1000000-1005000)/1005000 \cdot 360/60$ however i think that this is not a proper aswer.

Would it be like $1000000\cdot(1+0.08\cdot1/4)\approx1020000$ instead of $1$ mln?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  At maturity the security will pay $1\ 000\ 000$ plus interest.  How much is that?  You paid $1\ 005\ 000$ and get the above amount in $60$ days.  How much is your absolute profit or loss?  Now express your profit or loss as a percentage and scale that up to a year.  Your computation is close to that, missing the first point about how much the security pays at maturity.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: No, because the interest is only paid for $90$ days, while the $8\%$ presumably is an annual interest rate.

Comment: Thus $8\% \cdot 2/3$?

Comment: No, if you use a 360 day year (is that why you have 360 in your equation?) then $90$ days is exactly $1/4$ year.  Otherwise it is close.

Comment: Ok i was thinking about 60 days in question, my mistake.